# How to tell in Python if I am running on a Beowulf cluster?

Tags: python, linux, cluster-computing

I have a program that I run on a number of different machines, including one cluster. Currently, I check if I am on the cluster by finding the computer's hostname, and if it is the name of the cluster, I add distributed elements to the program, namely pestat and qsub calls. I am trying to make the program more portable, and am stuck here.

Is there a straightforward way to check if there are slave nodes attached, or how many are attached? I have searched a number of standard modules, including os, sys, socket, platform, and haven't found anything I can use. I have considered using a try/except block around running pestat, but I feel like there should be something better.

Edit: For the record, I am willing to use a linux/bash solution, or look up environment variables that would say if I am on a cluster.

Comment: Python has no specific Beowulf cluster support, no. Isn't there a command line utility that you could utilise? How would you detect this information from a shell, or from C or from any other language?

Comment: I have been looking into environment variables, which would be available in bash using sysconf (also available in Python using os.sysconf()) but haven't found a particular variable that says how many slave nodes, or a boolean flag for if it has any. So far, all I have been able to find requires that you know you are on a cluster and then you can deal with it.

Comment: why not just assume there is a cluster? and if it throws an error you know you are not on a cluster

Comment: @JoranBeasley That is what I am leaning to, as I referenced the use of a try/except.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to jump around a little with this explanation. Let me know if I am overshooting the request. Based off your description it sounds like you are using TORQUE or PBSpro. Given that there is currently no support to detect a cluster via python you could:

1) Check the path for the binaries. This means the script is no longer host dependent.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import subprocess

    command_to_run = "qstat -q"

    p = subprocess.Popen(command_to_run, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        output, error = p.communicate()
    match = re.search(r'command not found', error)
    if match:
        """something...
    match = re.search(r'Queue', output)
    if match:
        """something else...
```

This allows you to do some more complex logic. For example detecting if a cluster is down or up. You may not want to submit if we have the commands in the path but they are returning a connection error e.g. "connection rejected".

2) On each system you could write your own python module and try to import it via the script. If that fails then you know you are on a normal system. This could be managed via puppet and distributed accordingly.

Comment: That is very similar to what I am implementing currently. I am "try"ing to run pestat, and then checking each node to see if it is "free", "off", or "down". If pestat doesn't exist, then it throws an exception, at which point I know I am not on a cluster.